# Not able to see the file contents

Tags: vi, cat

I am using 12.04 Ubuntu cloud image.But when I am using `vi` for example `vi p1.c` to create a file I am not able to see what are the contents I am adding to it.

But when I am using `cat p1.c` I am able to see the contents what I have added.

Kindly help me out .

Comment: when you do `vi p1.c` what comes up on the screen?

Comment: black screen ...nothing I am able to see

Answer (score -2):

download nano, you can see file content like example 
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf 
to see and edit your DNS setting

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question is not about how to edit a file, but why `vi` doesn't show the file properly. That's not an answer to the latter.

Comment: WTH i gave you solution to use a better and easier editor, fine keep going with your vi

Comment: its vim not vi anyway